# Mudar titulos iguais

Tags: php

Tenho um `foreach` com resultados iguais sendo impressos, preciso mudar os que estiverem iguais.

Um exemplo do código é esse:

```
foreach ($courses as $key => $course) {
    var_dump($course->fullname);
}
```

Dentro do foreach o resultado é esse dando um `var_dump($course->fullname);`

```
string(6) "Nome 1" 
string(6) "Nome 2" 
string(6) "Nome 1"
```

Esse é o `var_dump($course);`

```
array(3) 
    { [1]=> object(stdClass)#442 (1) { ["fullname"]=> string(6) "Nome 1" } 
    { [2]=> object(stdClass)#443 (1) { ["fullname"]=> string(6) "Nome 2" } 
    { [3]=> object(stdClass)#444 (1) { ["fullname"]=> string(6) "Nome 1" } 
}
```

Como mudo o `fullname` dos resultados iguais ?

Comment: Você quer alterar o nome por exemplo Nome1 que tem dois para outro Nome?

Comment: sim!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Qual nome você quer alterar, existe um padrão, por exemplo tem 3 nomes iguais 1 vai ficar com o mesmo nome e os outros dois ??

Comment: vou colocar um sufixo nos nomes, exemplo: "Nome 1 - 1", "Nome 1 - 2" para todos iguais, podem ter vários...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode fazer assim:

```
<?php
$courses = array((object) array("fullname" => "Nome 1"), (object) array("fullname" => "Nome 2"), (object) array("fullname" => "Nome 2"), (object) array("fullname" => "Nome 1"), (object) array("fullname" => "Nome 1"), (object) array("fullname" => "Nome 2"));
$names = array(); // criamos um array vazio para guardar os nomes, que ficam como a key, e respetiva contagem

foreach($courses as $key => $course) {
    if(!isset($names[$course->fullname])) { // se o nome não existir ainda no nosso array
        $names[$course->fullname] = 0; // vamos iniciar a contagem do nome a 0 ex: $names['Nome 1'] = 0
    }
    $names[$course->fullname] += 1; // incrementamos 1 à contagem, quantas vezes aquele nome apareceu
    $courses[$key]->fullname = $course->fullname. ' - ' .$names[$course->fullname]; // criamos o nosso novo nome no array principal
}
```

Sendo que `$courses` passa a ficar, fazendo `print_r($courses);`:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [fullname] => Nome 1 - 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [fullname] => Nome 2 - 1 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [fullname] => Nome 2 - 2 ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [fullname] => Nome 1 - 2 ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [fullname] => Nome 1 - 3 ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [fullname] => Nome 2 - 3 ) )
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](http://ideone.com/GDW7SY)